# videoslasher video download script php

Tags: php, curl

I got a problem with downloading video from videoslasher.com. I wrote a script to get source link and it is working fine.

Example link:

> http://storage2.videoslasher.com/free/K/K1/K1Z6TBW88QCM.flv?h=XeahiwUFe_yHiduYx5EzBg&e=1377200810

But when i am downloading with script i get 403 (forbidden).
Code downloading video:

```
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0';
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: pl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
$headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';


$ch = curl_init();        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.videoslasher.com/static/player/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.7.swf');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 4096000);
echo curl_exec($ch);     
curl_close($ch);
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: I get 403 forbidden when trying to access the URL in my browser. Perhaps it requires the user to be logged in?

Comment: This is example link. This link does not work (it has expired i think). I think problem is that, videoslasher is blocking bots/scripts